# Posting using test user's profile error on Facebook: An unknown error occurred

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post from an app on with a test user on his wall and I receive the next
error response from the API:

```
(#1) An unknown error occurred
```

When i create the user I add these permissions:

'basic_info',
      'read_stream',
      'status_update',
      'photo_upload',
      'video_upload',
      'create_note',
      'publish_stream',
      'share_item',
      'read_insights',
      'publish_actions'

Do you have any idea why is this happenning?

**Later Edit**
The request for creating a test user:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/xxx/accounts/test-users?access_token=xxxx&permissions=basic_info%2Cread_stream%2Cstatus_update%2Cphoto_upload%2Cvideo_upload%2Ccreate_note%2Cpublish_stream%2Cshare_item%2Cread_insights%2Cpublish_actions&installed=true
```

Comment: Can you add in the entire request you are making with facebook? (without tokens, obviously)

Comment: Does removing the permissions one by one change things?

Comment: Yes, I get a 200 error: The user has not granted the application the permission to automatically publish feed stories

Comment: You mean an actual test user as FB provides for your app? If so, try with a “real” user – Facebook’s test user system has to many bugs to be a good choice for testing under _real_ conditions.

Comment: With a real user I will have "spammy" problems. I want to use this for tests that run at least five to ten times a day and Facebook may set a feed limit for my app.